# trying to check if user exists with php

Tags: php, sql

hi i am trying to make a php script that checks if a user is in the database only it gives me the error 
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\userExist.php on line 22

below is the code

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'k3462_top-tree');

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$userName = $_GET['userName'];

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

echo "<table>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['userName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = $userName";

$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)>=1){
    echo "user exists";
}
else {
    echo "user doesnt exist";
}


mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_query()` returns false in case of failure. Therefore you're trying to do `mysqli_num_rows(false)` which is illegal. I suggest you check your query.

Comment: Despire the answers below, do not directly input variables into your query *ever*, especially not from GET or POST or the like. This is a recipe for sql injection and possible data leaks. Use prepared statements or proper database abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your query that fill the variable `$result1` with `false`. That occurs your error. Try my example below. I just added `'` around `$userName` in your query and an if statement around your `mysqli_num_rows` function.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'k3462_top-tree');
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";

$userName = $_GET['userName'];
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

echo "<table>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['userName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = '$userName'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1);


if( $result1 )  {
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)>=1){
      echo "user exists";
  }
  else {
      echo "user doesnt exist";
  }
} else {
  echo "query or db error";
}


mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score -2):

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = '$userName'";